# Highcharts: Irregular time intervals of datetime x-axis not hovering over all the points

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, intervals

I hope someone could point me to the right direction here. I have a series of data that spans over an irregular datetime intervals. But hovering over the points shows only the first date point.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rkcqxyn/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Debt Obligations'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Debt'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y}'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Debt Obligation',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 6, 7), 4500],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 24), 5454],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 23), 222],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 21), 1000]
        ]
    }]
});
```

});

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You must learn to use the console to debug.
If you check your fiddle, and have the console enabled, you will see that it displays an "informational" message:

Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15

If you check the above link, it says that your data isn't sorted beforehand. That's your problem.

Indeed, if you put the data in this order:

```
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 21), 1000],
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 23), 222],
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 24), 5454],
[Date.UTC(2014, 6, 7), 4500]
```

It works as expected.